# How to extract specific data from grep command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, grep

I'm trying to write my own script to tell me if I've used more than 500 MiB of my data.
I'm using vnstat -d for the information about data usage.
`vnstat -d` [Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx4Ww.png)
[image]

Output should be:

1. Only from the "Total column"
2. Only have values greater than 500.

I want only values from the "total"column. My output lists data from all the columns.
Better clear from the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `vnstat -d | grep -a [0-9] `; //get numerical values in i (-a tag as vnstat outputs in binary)
do 
    NUMBER=$(echo $i | grep -o '[5-9][0-9][0-9]'); //store values >500 in a var called NUMBER
    echo $NUMBER;
done;
```

I'm a self-learning  newb here so please try not to bash (pun) me.

Current output which I'm receiving from above script:

```
600
654
925
884
923
871
967
868
```

My desired output should be:

```
654   
923    
967
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1).  People here regard that as evil.

Comment: `output_cmd | awk -F\| '{print $3}` could get your started. Read the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Comment: @Typedragon33 : Why should 600 be excluded? After all, 600 > 500!

Comment: @user1934428 the entry 600 isn't from `total` column.

Comment: Correct, but in your code you do a `grep -o '[5-9][0-9][0-9]'`, which searches **all** numbers in the line and not only the one in the column titled _total_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified:

```
#/bin/bash
if [[ $(( $(vnstat -d --oneline|cut -d';' -f6|cut -d. -f1|paste -sd '+') )) -ge 500 ]];then
  echo 500 Mb reached
fi
```

(What the script does, is it takes the specified field from the oneliner CSV-like output from each interface, then cuts the whole numbers and does a SUM of them. And then it compares if that sum is equal or greater than `500`. And if it is, `then` it outputs a message)

Note:

`-f6` will parse the  "total for today" traffic

you can replace it with:

`-f4` = rx for today

`-f5` = tx for today

Comment: Wow this actually worked! This is genius @Ron. I'm still new and don't understand any of it. But wow man.

Comment: you can adjust the output or `echo` of course, and you can also check `--oneline` formats in `man vnstat` for more output options..

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse a pipe delimited table and check only a specific column, there are tools more appropriate than `grep` for this job, for example you could write a small bash script where you use the `cut` command to extract the data and process them, or `awk`.

Here is a solution with `awk`. We print numbers `> 500` of that column, `total`. Send your command output to

```
awk -F "|" '($3+0>=500){print $3}'
```

- `-F` sets the field delimiter to `|`
- `$3+0` is used to convert a string starting with a number to that number, so that
  we can handle it as a number and do the comparison.

---

Now, if you really want to extract all values having column `total > 500 MiB`, 
then the expected output should include all values expressed in `GiB`, as they are 
`> 1000 MiB`, for example the minimum value in your evil screenshot is 0.98 GiB which is 1003 MiB. So we can add this to the first condition.

```
awk -F "|" '($3 ~ /GiB/ || $3+0>500){print $3}'
```

---

Now if you want the output to be only integers in MiB, we can modify it to:

```
awk -F "|" '($3 ~ /GiB/){$3=1024*$3+0} ($3+0>500){printf "%.0f\n",$3}'
```

Here we convert all GiB values to MiB, and we do the comparison after that.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate and kind explanation! I will take it step by step and come back after I've practiced `awk`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `vnstat -d`; do # get each lines
  VALUE=$(echo $i | cut -d\| -f3) # get total value with unit, in case you want to check for GiB values
  NUMBER=$(echo $VALUE | grep -o '[0-9.*]' | cut -d. -f1); # split the string by '|', get the number part, store the integer part into NUMBER
  if [[ $NUMBER -ge 500 && "$VALUE" == *"MiB"* || "$VALUE" == *"GiB"* ]]; then # if the number is greater than or equals to 500 OR it's in GiB
    echo $VALUE; # echo the value
  fi
done
```

Of course you can strip out the GiB checking if you wanted to.

Edit: Added IFS=$'\n' at the beginning. This allows the for loop to use endline as the delimiter.

Comment: That `for` loop processes each word, not each line.

Comment: Not working. Here's the output I got. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the output I got https://textuploader.com/1mghl

Comment: Oops. I added one more line at the and for the for loop to loop through each line

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `awk`. Something like (untested)

```
vnstat -d | awk '$1 == "estimated" { exit }
                 ($9 == "GiB" && $8 > 0.5) ||
                 ($9 == "MiB" && $8 > 500) { print $8 " " $9 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

vnstat has several options to format the output.
You can use `vnstat --dumpdb`, `vnstat --json` or `vnstat --xml` to have well-formatted data that you can then parse more easily (for example with `jq` if you choose the JSON format).

For example :

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | .days[1] | .rx'
```

will extract the number of kiB received on the interface `eth0` yesterday (the day `0` is today, `1` is yesterday, etc)

To have the total rx+tx, you can use

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | .total | .rx+.tx'
```

You can also sum several days, for example today and yesterday :

```
vnstat --json | jq '.interfaces[] | select(.id == "eth0") | .traffic | [.days[0,1] | .rx+.tx] | add'
```

And instead of days, you can references "months" or "hours" (for `hours`, be careful, the id has not the same meaning, it's the reference of the hour).